# Issue with forecasting a time series that is a white noise using ARMA

Tags: stationarity, arma

I am working on stock prices and stock returns and I'm supposed to do some forecast on these data. The stock prices series is not stationary and even if the stock returns series is, it is a white noise. I can't do any forecasting on the stock returns since it is a white noise. My professor suggested that I should **adjust** an AR(1) or MA(1) process, but I don't really understand what she means by adjusting these processes?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Probably means to transform the time series with first differencing (to deal with a trend) and/or log (to make the trend more linear) to create a stationary time series that can be modeled with ARMA.  Here is a reference  https://otexts.com/fpp2/stationarity.html.

Alternately, you might choose an exponential smoothing model instead, which compared to ARIMA, has a more robust and elegant way to deal with trends.

Answer (score -1):

What she probably means is to detect anomalous data points (pulses) or a mean shift or a trend change then adjust the original series for these effects. What she probably means is that if the series has a model where the errors have non-constant variance requiring either weighted least squares or a power transformation adjust accordingly.

Comment: Hi: granger wrote a paper called "forecasting white noise" that I've always intended to read but haven't had the chance. ( or maybe just been lazy ). I have no idea if it's related to your professor's suggestion but it might be worth taking a look at. His papers are often obtainable on the net so google for it. I would but I have to go somewhere right now.